# Move custom list items which are inside a list view to another custom list

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, administration, move, content-and-structure

I have 2 custom SharePoint online lists, one list for active items and the other for archived items (items with status closed + have been modified for 2 years), where the 2 lists have the same content type and settings.

so does SharePoint online support moving list items inside a list view to another list? and preserve the metadata of the moved  list items?

Thanks

Hint, i already tried the content and structure page , but it did not work for me, where i open another question @ [The Content and Structure page message "The Content and Structure page (sitemanager.aspx) is now available only to site collection administrators"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/281017/the-content-and-structure-page-message-the-content-and-structure-page-sitemana)

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a workflow in the source list. Make sure that there are same columns in both lists.
[image]

2.Use flow template.

[Move items from one SharePoint list to another](https://asia.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/24b901e0015f4e839b39e49c76cb8771/move-items-from-one-sharepoint-list-to-another/)

3.Use PowerShell.

[SharePoint Online: Copy List Items from One List to Another using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/01/sharepoint-online-copy-list-items-to-another-list-using-powershell.html)

Comment: inside workflow 2013 there is no option to copy itme, i can only see copy document...

Comment: i tried workflow 2010 but the copy item will not preserve the metadata of the items such as created-by, modified-by + the versions will not get preserved.. so not sure

Comment: To move items with versions, I suggest you use "save list as a template".

Comment: but saving as template will work for one time, what if we need to move closed items after one month for example....

Comment: If you want to move items every month automatically, only workflow or flow can be achieved, but versions cannot be retained.